# Choosing a random mp4 file from directory in processing

Tags: random, processing, mp4

I have a directory with a processing script and some .mp4 files, how do i choose a random one to display?

Answer (score 1):

[Break your problem down into smaller steps.](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program)

Can you write a program that simply lists all of the files in a directory? The `File` class might help, and [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) is your best friend.

Can you write a program that takes that list of files and creates an array or `ArrayList` that contains all of them?

Can you write a program that takes an array or `ArrayList` and chooses a random element from it? Use hard-coded `String` values for testing.

When you get all of these individual steps working, you can combine them into a single program that chooses a random file from a directory. If you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just that step, and we'll go from there.